# Wix Patch error - The feature you are trying to use on a network resource that is unavailable

Tags: installation, wix, patch

We are using WIX Installer for our application deployment. We are generating Patches using wix. While we try to uninstall the patch the following error is coming

"The feature you are trying to use on a network resource that is unavailable"

It is expecting previous version MSI.

Which property we need to set for mainteining baseline cache. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the path uninstall process needs to repair the original installation in order to restore it to its original state.

A possible solution is this:

- open the patch PCP file with Orca
- set the SEQUENCE_DATA_GENERATION_DISABLED property to 0 and save the changes
- rebuild the patch using the modified PCP

This will make the patch automatically generate the patch sequencing information and the original MSI should no longer be required for the patch installation.

If you don’t have access to the PCP file or the original MSI is still required, most likely the installed files are modified or removed after being copied on the target machine. In this case there are two solutions:

- provide the original MSI when prompted

or

- make sure that the installed files are not modified by your application or some other process

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.. We are using Purely WIX. Is this property available in purely WIX also?

Comment: It's a Windows Installer property which can be used by any setup authoring tool.